# C# Writing english numbers in file when windows use arabic UI

Tags: c#, numbers, culture, arabic

My windows use arabic language.
When i write numbers in a file it appears in arabic format,
but i need to write in english format,

although i use this two lines before writing to file:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

and i use `string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US") , myNumbers)`

why this happen?

Comment: How do you write to the file?

Comment: See my answer, below.  Code does not display in comments very well!

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a numeric format:

```
string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:n}", myNumbers)
```

When I run the following code on my US English Windows 7 machine, I get identical results.  What format are you expecting?

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(new CultureInfo("ar-SA"), "{0:n}", 123456789));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:n}", 123456789));
```

123,456,789.00

123,456,789.00